# Create as Select and add an extra column

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a MySQL table as a copy of another table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
```

The twist is that I want, if possible, to add at the time of creation another empty column, that will be populated at a later time.

I know that I can just create it as above and use ALTER TABLE afterwards, but my thinking is that, given a large amount of data, the ALTER is gonna take a long time (please contradict me if this is wrong), that can be saved if what I want is possible.

So, say I want an extra `extra_col - varchar(64)`, what would my original query be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented under [`CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table-select.html):

> You can create one table from another by adding a `SELECT` statement at the end of the `CREATE TABLE` statement:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;
> ```
>
> MySQL creates new columns for all elements in the `SELECT`.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> Notice that the columns from the `SELECT` statement are appended to the right side of the table, not overlapped onto it.
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> In a table resulting from `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`, columns named only in the `CREATE TABLE` part come first. Columns named in both parts or only in the `SELECT` part come after that. The data type of `SELECT` columns can be overridden by also specifying the column in the `CREATE TABLE` part.

Therefore:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl (
  extra_col VARCHAR(64)
) SELECT * FROM orig_tbl
```

Comment: Shoudn't this produce a table where the extra column is the first and all the columns from `orig_tbl` follows? It would make more sense (to me) to add the extra one in the end, but that's just an opinion...

Comment: @Cynical: Alas, the MySQL developers held a different opinion.  I think both arguments are probably equally valid, so perhaps you could suggest a feature to extent the syntax such that one can specify where to place columns?  Given Oracle's management of the project, you might even find it gets introduced during your lifetime (but don't hold your breath).

Comment: Thanks for this. I tested it and for me, using mysql 5.7, the `extra_col` is the first column and the columns from `orig_tbl` follow on the right.

Answer (score 2):

@user1703809 You have a workaround if you want to place the added column at the end by placing the extra column in the Select statement as :

```
CREATE |TEMPORARY| TABLE IF NOT EXISTS new_tbl 
SELECT *, REPEAT('-',64) extra_col
FROM orig_tbl;
```

This will create your new table with an added column "extra_col" - varchar(64). Furthermore, you may create the table as temporary if it suits you, and if you just want to create an empty table for further use, just add a "LIMIT 0" at the end of the statement. 
Furthermore, this way, you may add a column in any position of the field list at the Select statement.
It's been sometime since you asked the question but I'm still hoping to be of some help.